# Send Audio and String Data on socket in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, audio, stream

I need help about building a connection which can send Audio and String together and split them in client side. Now I can send the audio but when I add other data type, the received data is noisy in another side:

Here I removed send String Code :

Please help me.

This is the server code:

```
package tw.rascov.MediaStreamer;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MediaStreamServer {
    static final int frequency = 44100;
    static final int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
    static final int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    boolean isRecording;
    int recBufSize;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Socket socket;
    AudioRecord audioRecord;


public MediaStreamServer(final Context ctx, final int port) {
    recBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
    audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, recBufSize);
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Intent intent = new Intent()
            .setAction("tw.rascov.MediaStreamer.ERROR")
            .putExtra("msg", e.toString());
        ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);
        return;
    }

    new Thread() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[recBufSize];
        public void run() {
            try
            {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Intent intent = new Intent()
                    .setAction("tw.rascov.MediaStreamer.ERROR")
                    .putExtra("msg", e.toString());
                ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);
                return;
            }
            audioRecord.startRecording();
            isRecording = true;
            while (isRecording) {
                int readSize = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, recBufSize);
                try {
                    socket.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, readSize);

                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Intent intent = new Intent()
                        .setAction("tw.rascov.MediaStreamer.ERROR")
                        .putExtra("msg", e.toString());
                    ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);
                    break;
                }
            }
            audioRecord.stop();
            try { socket.close(); }
            catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }.start();
}

public void stop() {
    isRecording = false;
    try { serverSocket.close(); }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}

}
```

And Client code :

```
public class MediaStreamClient {
    static final int frequency = 44100;
    static final int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
    static final int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    boolean isPlaying;
    int playBufSize;
    Socket socket;
    AudioTrack audioTrack;

public MediaStreamClient(final Context ctx, final String ip, final int port) {
    playBufSize=AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
    //audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, playBufSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            frequency,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize (
                    frequency,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
            ),
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM
    );
    audioTrack.setStereoVolume(1f, 1f);

    new Thread() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[playBufSize];
        public void run() {
            try
            {
                socket = new Socket(ip, port);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Intent intent = new Intent()
                    .setAction("tw.rascov.MediaStreamer.ERROR")
                    .putExtra("msg", e.toString());
                ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);
                return;
            }
            audioTrack.play();
            isPlaying = true;
            while (isPlaying)
            {
                int readSize = 0;
                try
                {
                    DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    readSize = dIn.read(buffer);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Intent intent = new Intent()
                        .setAction("tw.rascov.MediaStreamer.ERROR")
                        .putExtra("msg", e.toString());
                    ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);
                    break;
                }
                    audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, readSize);

            }
            audioTrack.stop();
            try { socket.close(); }
            catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }.start();
}

public void stop() {
    isPlaying = false;
}

public void setVolume(float lvol, float rvol) {
    audioTrack.setStereoVolume(lvol, rvol);
}
}
```